# Internal redirect from subdomain to root via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I use following .htaccess-code to convert my URLs to user-friendly ones:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

Now I want to redirect requests from the www-subdomain to the rootdomain, e.g. if the user requests `http://www.mydomain.com/stuff/`, he gets to see `http://mydomain.com/stuff/` in the address bar of his browser.

All attempts I've made resulted in external redirects, so the user gets to see the rewritten URL, e.g. `http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=stuff`.

How do I perform an internal redirect, so that the address bar doesn't change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these rules (put them into **.htaccess** file in root folder):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# canonical domain name (no www please)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]

# nice url handler
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You most likely had the correct rules already (based on your description) .. you just had them in wrong order. You have to keep in mind -- order matters.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, LazyOne! Your code did the job. :)

Comment: Done! I had to register first. ;)